# Why does my phone keep getting stuck when performing a backup?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, backup

I have rooted my phone and currently have an older version of Cyanogen mod on my Sprint HTC Hero.  When I try to perform a backup using Rom Manager, the phone tries to reboot, but it never finishes booting.  Any ideas what is causing that and how I can back up my phone in order to upgrade to the latest version of Cyanogen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Rom Manager and flash an older version of clockwork recovery.  Then flash the latest version of it.  Does that help?

Otherwise: do you get any sort of error messages?